# How can I change or turn off jQuery UI accordion's fixed-height inline style?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a <p> in a jQuery UI accordion that appears:

```
<p class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" style="height: 184px " role="tabpanel">
```

Earlier, when I had several text links in there, it fit perfectly. However, now I have image links, and the images are sharply clipped.

I can duct tape the matter by adding additional <br /> tabs to get more space, but I'd like the accordion panel to include all images, one above the other, and correctly sized.

Comment: Have you tried the [clearStyle](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-clearStyle) or [fillSpace](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-fillSpace) options

Comment: Can you post an example of your accordion on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with the jQuery Accordion, and I just found the fix!

Simply add this CSS code at the top of your page. It will override the auto crop happening on the thumbnails:

```
.ui-accordion-content {
  min-height:auto !important;  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In If I understand your question correctly you need to tell the accordion to base its height off the content.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        heightStyle: "content"
    });
});
```

This is stated and shown on the jQuery UI site here: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#no-auto-height

Hopefully this is what you are looking for.